# How do I show that $\gamma$ is a continuous function?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, analysis

> Prove that the unit ball $B^{n} = \{x ∈ R^{n}: |x| ≤ 1\}$ is path connected.
>
> Solution: Use a straight-line path: if $x, y ∈ B^{n}$, then $γ(t) = tx + (1 − t)y$ is a path in $B^{n}$ since $|γ(t)| ≤ |t||x| + |1 − t||y| ≤ t + 1 − t = 1$.

Using the above example, I would like to show that $S=\{(x,y,z):x^{2}+y^{2}+z^{2}=1\}$ is path-connected using the function $\gamma$ with $a,b \in S$. In order to show that $S$ is path-connected, I must show that $\gamma$ is a continuous function. How do I show that $\gamma$ is continuous?

Comment: Your $\gamma$ is not defined on $S$. So you cannot use it. There are other arguments showing $S$ to be path-connected.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma: I'm actually very confused. Why then is $\gamma (t)$ defined on $B^{n}$ in the example provided?

Comment: that’s what the last line in the quote proves: all norms never exceed $1$.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma: When does the norm exceed $1$ in $S$?

Comment: Your $\gamma$ is a affine linear function in $t$, and these type of functions are continuous.

Comment: @Fakemistake: But I still don't understand why $\gamma$ is not defined on $S$.

Comment: @K.M it should be exactly equal to $1$ in $S$ and that’s only the case in the endpoints.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can show that $\gamma$ is Lipschitz with Lipschitz constant $\Vert x-y\Vert$. In a metric space that shows continuity.

Comment: Thanks, but what exactly is meant by a metric space that shows continuity?

Comment: A Lipshcitz function between metric spaces is continuous. So showing that the map is Lipschitz shows continuity. And you have a metric space structure induced by the norm you wrote.

Answer (score 2):

$\mathbb{R}^3\setminus \{0\}$ is path-connected (it's easy to avoid $0$ in any path between points $x,y \neq 0$, using two straight line segments joined together).

And $S$ is the continuous image of $\mathbb{R}^n\setminus \{0\}$ under the continuous map $r(x)=\frac{1}{\|x\|}\cdot x$.

And continuous images of path-connected spaces are path-connected.